# What's the difference between getUsableSpace and getUnallocatedSpace of FileStore class

Tags: java, nio

I've read the definition in the documentation and performed some searches on the Internet, but it is still not clear to me.  What's the difference between `getUsableSpace()` and `getUnallocatedSpace()` in the `FileStore` class?

Answer (score 5):

From the [FileStore class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html)

> getUnallocatedSpace() Returns the number of unallocated bytes in the file store.
>
> getUsableSpace()
> Returns the number of bytes available **to this Java virtual machine** on the file store.

So there is possibly more unallocated space than usable space.

You can test it with the following code snippet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

public class TestFileStore {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (FileStore fileStore : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
            System.out.println(fileStore.name());
            System.out.println("Unallocated space: " + fileStore.getUnallocatedSpace());
            System.out.println("Unused space: " + fileStore.getUsableSpace());
            System.out.println("************************************");
        }
    }
}
```

This is an excerpt of my output

```
************************************
tmpfs
Unallocated space: 206356480
Unused space: 206356480
************************************
/dev/sda6
Unallocated space: 1089933312
Unused space: 790126592
************************************
```

Comment: My experience is on Windows getUnallocatedSpace() == getUsableSpace() but on Linux, ext filesystems reserve 5% of the space for root (https://serverfault.com/questions/228514/free-disk-vs-available-disk).  So a non-root user on Linux using an ext filesystem will see a difference between getUnallocatedSpace() and getUsableSpace().

Answer (score 1):

From peeking at the documentation, I would assume that `getUsableSpace` is oriented toward the current java vm, while `getUnallocatedSpace` refers to all unallocated space on the file store.

Answer (score 1):

`getUsableSpace`：
Returns the number of bytes **available to this Java virtual machine** on the file store. on the file store.

`getUnallocatedSpace`:
Returns the number of unallocated bytes in the file store.

Note that bytes available to this JVM can be less than the unallocated space, for write permissions and other operating system restrictions.